# Two singletons referencing each other prevent the initialization from ending

Tags: swift, singleton

I have a situation where I want to have two singleton objects that hold references to each other.

**ManagerA:**

```
import Foundation

class ManagerA: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = ManagerA()

    let managerB = ManagerB.sharedInstance

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

**ManagerB** (in this example symmetric to ManagerA):

```
import Foundation

class ManagerB: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = ManagerB()

    let managerA = ManagerA.sharedInstance

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Manager A is being created in the AppDelegate.
Unfortunately this leads to the ViewController not being shown anymore, so I assume the initialization process is endless.

How can I solve the initialization?

I'd like to stay with the pattern. Both managers are used throughout the app from various places and the singleton pattern seems fit. Yet it'd be useful if they could also directly access each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is infinite recursion.

You can fix that in several ways.

Here I am making one of the 2 properties a computed property, look

```
final class ManagerA {
    static let sharedInstance = ManagerA()
    var managerB = { return ManagerB.sharedInstance }
    private init() { }
}

final class ManagerB {
    static let sharedInstance = ManagerB()
    let managerA = ManagerA.sharedInstance
    private init() { }
}
```

### More

However do you really need a property to reference a singleton? The beauty of a singleton is that you can retrieve the only allowed instance of a class from everywhere simply writing `ClassName.sharedInstance`.

So you could easily remove both the `managerA` and `managerB` properties.

### Some changes I made

- I removed the `NSObject` stuff since you don't really need that don't you?
- I made your classes `final`, otherwise someone could subclass them, add an init and break the singletons paradigm

Comment: @ColGraff: Thanks for the comment. I used a __computed property__ instead of a __weak stored property__ because in the second case there still is infinite recursion.

Comment: It's too early for me, I realized this just before you commented!

Comment: @ColGraff: No problem ;) However in general you are right, `weak` (or `unowned`) is the best way to manage (and signal) you are avoiding a strong reference cycle.

Comment: Thanks for this nice and clean solution! One little thing that's missing is a `()` on line three to actually evaluate the closure for the computed property `managerB`.

Comment: ...or rather not since since then it's the same as initially. Hmm.. So the property needs to be evaluated to be accessed then, as in `managerB().doSomething()`

Comment: One possible solution seems to postpone this initialization with `lazy` as in `lazy var managerB = { return ManagerB.sharedInstance }()`. The main reason I'm using these properties in the first place is mostly readability & brevety, oatherwise I'd have to replace each instance of `managerA` with `ManagerA.sharedInstace`. Which would be ok, but I find the other version better readable, especially since I'm using this object a lot in several methods.

Comment: @FrederickSquid: You should not put the `()` because that's a computed property.

Comment: 2 reasons why one uses properties to store a reference to a singleton: 1) To make the dependency of the singleton clear, 2) For dependency injection, i.e. to replace for testing purposes the singleton by a mock object.